# Polars Customized Function Returns Multiple Columns

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

`_func` is designed to return two columns:

```py
from polars.type_aliases import IntoExpr, IntoExprColumn
import polars as pl

def _func(x: IntoExpr):
    x1 = x+1
    x2 = x+2
    return pl.struct([x1, x2])
    
df = pl.DataFrame({"test": np.arange(1, 11)})
df.with_columns(
    _func(pl.col("test")).alias(["test1", "test2"])
)
```

I have tried to wrap the return values using `pl.struct` but it didn't work.

Expected output:

```py
shape: (10, 3)
test test1 test2
i32 i32 i32
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   4   5
4   5   6
5   6   7
6   7   8
7   8   9
8   9   10
9   10  11
10  11  12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you cannot or don't want to change the function, so we need to work with sequence of expressions returned by this function. Also I want the answer to be able to accommodate for more than 2 columns, so I don't have to specifically `alias` each column.

The problem in your case is at the end you have a sequence of `Expr` with the same name, so you need to rename them at some point before executing.

Solution might depend on what kind of names do you plan to use for your columns.
You can do something like this:

```py
def _func(x: IntoExpr):
    x1 = x+1
    x2 = x+2
    return x1, x2

df.with_columns(
    x.alias(f"test{i+1}") for i,x in enumerate(_func(pl.col("test")))
)

# alternatevely
# df.with_columns(
#    x.name.suffix(f"{i+1}") for i,x in enumerate(_func(pl.col("test")))
#)

┌──────┬───────┬───────┐
│ test ┆ test1 ┆ test2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i32  ┆ i32   ┆ i32   │
╞══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2     ┆ 3     │
│ 2    ┆ 3     ┆ 4     │
│ 3    ┆ 4     ┆ 5     │
│ 4    ┆ 5     ┆ 6     │
│ 5    ┆ 6     ┆ 7     │
│ 6    ┆ 7     ┆ 8     │
│ 7    ┆ 8     ┆ 9     │
│ 8    ┆ 9     ┆ 10    │
│ 9    ┆ 10    ┆ 11    │
│ 10   ┆ 11    ┆ 12    │
└──────┴───────┴───────┘
```

For custom names you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
f.with_columns(
    x.alias(n) for x, n in zip(_func(pl.col('test')), ["a","b"])
)

┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ test ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i32  ┆ i32 ┆ i32 │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ 2    ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ 3    ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
│ 4    ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │
│ 5    ┆ 6   ┆ 7   │
│ 6    ┆ 7   ┆ 8   │
│ 7    ┆ 8   ┆ 9   │
│ 8    ┆ 9   ┆ 10  │
│ 9    ┆ 10  ┆ 11  │
│ 10   ┆ 11  ┆ 12  │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Or you can use the fact that [`with_columns()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html) accepts `**named_exprs` as an argument,convert list of expressions into dict and unpack it:

```py
df.with_columns(
    **dict(zip(['a','b'], _func(pl.col('test'))))
)

┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ test ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i32  ┆ i32 ┆ i32 │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ 2    ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ 3    ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
│ 4    ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │
│ 5    ┆ 6   ┆ 7   │
│ 6    ┆ 7   ┆ 8   │
│ 7    ┆ 8   ┆ 9   │
│ 8    ┆ 9   ┆ 10  │
│ 9    ┆ 10  ┆ 11  │
│ 10   ┆ 11  ┆ 12  │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with [`pl.struct`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html) is fine. However, at the moment, you create a struct column with two fields having an equal name. This can be fixed by giving one struct field a different name as follows.

```
def _func(x: IntoExpr):
    x1 = x+1
    x2 = x+2
    return pl.struct([x1, x2.name.prefix("another_")])

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        _func(pl.col("test")).alias("struct_col")
    )
)
```

This creates a single struct column *struct_col* with fields *test* and *another_test*. You could then easily unnest *struct_col* into the two columns using [`pl.DataFrame.unnest`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness and consideration of execution speed, I have put all four apporaches mentioned to test, while complicating the calculations a bit. Also I want to add a 5th method for operations within `with_columns()` instead of calling `unnest()` outside of `with_columns()`:

```py
from polars.type_aliases import IntoExpr, IntoExprColumn
from typing import Iterable
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

def func1(x: IntoExpr):
    x1 = (x + 1) ** 2 + x.sin()
    x2 = x.exp() / x.log()
    return x1, x2

def func2(x: IntoExpr, aliases: Iterable[str]):
    x1 = (x + 1) ** 2 + x.sin()
    x2 = x.exp() / x.log()
    return pl.struct(x1.alias(aliases[0]), x2.alias(aliases[1]))

np.random.seed(42)
df = pl.DataFrame({"test": np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 100_000_000)})
df_lazy = df.lazy()
```

**Eager Executions:**

**Using `enumerate()`**:

```py
%%timeit
df.with_columns(
    x.alias(f"test{i+1}") 
    for i, x in enumerate(func1(pl.col("test")))
    )

4.17 s ± 131 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Using `zip()`**

```py
%%timeit
df.with_columns(
    x.alias(n) 
    for x, n in zip(
        func1(pl.col("test")),
        ["test1", "test2"]
        )
    )

4.09 s ± 35.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Using `**dict` and `zip()`**:

```py
%%timeit
df.with_columns(
    **dict(
        zip(
            ["test1", "test2"],
            func1(pl.col("test"))
            )
        )
    )

4.08 s ± 40.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Using `struct()`**:

```py
%%timeit
df.with_columns(
    func2(pl.col("test"), ["test1", "test2"]).alias("struct_col")
).unnest("struct_col")

4.07 s ± 27.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Using `struct` and `struct.field`**:

```py
%%timeit
df.with_columns(
    func2(pl.col("test"), ["test1", "test2"]).struct.field("test1"),
    func2(pl.col("test"), ["test1", "test2"]).struct.field("test2"),
)

4.52 s ± 180 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Lazy Executions**:
All queries finished from **4.08s** to **4.1** seconds. The differences are trivial.